# Laravel join with 3 Tables to Filter view table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I am building a logistic app.
I have 3 tables that look like this:
**users:** UserID
**service:** ServicesID
**providers_services:** ProviderID, ServiceID
providers_services table contains all services in the application provided by providers(users). that's means when a user register in the app as a provider they will select services that they will provide these stores into the providers_services table. a single user could have many services that they provide. in the dashboard, I fetch all users from the user's table (in blade view) and a select option with all services. I want when I select a service the table should be filtered and show me only the users (providers) that they provide the selected service.

This is my code :

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

public function getForm(Request $request)
{

    $getSerName = $request['ServiceName'];

    $dataReqServices    = DB::table('service')
    ->join('category','category.CategoryID','=','service.CategoryID')
    ->get();

    $users = DB::table('users')
   ->join('providers_services','providers_services.ProviderID','users.UserID')
   ->where('users.UserID','=',$getSerName)
    ->get();

    return view('push.notify', compact('users','dataReqServices'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use many to many relationships. Make sure you have this in your User model:

```
public function services()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany(Service::class);
}
```

And this in your Service model:

```
public function users()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

This is service_user_pivot_table content:

```
Schema::create('service_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('service_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');

            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('service_id')->references('id')->on('services');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
```

To return users, in your controller use:

```
public function index($id)
    {
        $services = Service::find($id);

        $users = $services->users;
        return view('home', compact('users'));
    }
```

This $id is passed on web.php routes, so it looks like this for me:

```
Route::get('/home/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
```

Where id is id of service. Make sure you also add this to your controller:

```
use App\Models\Service;
```

on the top.

Comment: why the service model, not the user model ($users = Service::where('id', $serviceId)->users()->orderBy('name')->get())?

Comment: Because you are getting users related to service: services()->users()->get(); Same as you want to, for example, get all photos from user: user()->photos()->get();

Comment: the problem is there is no direct relation between the user model and the service so all the ids are stored in the providers_services table

Comment: I updated the answer. Try the latest function in your controller to return users.